# Is a Farmer villager required to breed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In a village I found in desert, all villagers died, except the Librarian. I cured a Zombie Villager, that turned out to be another Librarian.

As [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Willingness) describes:

> *Additionally, villagers must be "willing" in order to breed. After
> mating, they will no longer be willing, and must be made willing
> again.*
>
> *Villagers may become willing when the player trades with them.
> Willingness is granted the first time a new offer is traded, or at a
> one-in-five chance on subsequent trades. Green particles will appear
> if the villager becomes willing by trading. This will not cause them
> to immediately seek out a mate, however.*
>
> *Villagers can also become willing by having either 3 bread, 12 carrots
> or 12 potatoes in one stack in their inventory. Any villager with an
> excess of food (usually farmers) will throw food to other villagers,
> allowing them to pick it up and obtain enough food to become willing.
> You can also throw bread, carrots, or potatoes at the villagers
> yourself to encourage breeding. Villagers will consume the required
> food upon becoming willing.*

I have traded with them until they don't want paper anymore, so I traded for the enchanted books, then traded with paper again. I gave them lots of bread, potatoes and carrots. None of them shows hearts, and I ran low on Emeralds, as I had traded them for enchanted books.

I'm planning to cure one more villager. I have searched how to breed and most tutorial uses the example of the Farmer. I can't find any mechanics that list needing a Farmer.

**Is a Farmer villager required to breed?**
If it is, do I need both Farmers to breed, or just one of them?
If it's not, is there any chance for my two Librarians breeding?
*Are there new mechanics on the latest 1.8.7 version of Minecraft?*

Comment: Note: this question and most answers refers to old breeding mechanics, which has been fundamentally changed with 1.14, and so, it's obsolete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No, you don't need a Farmer. But, for two villagers, you need at least 6 doors (that lead to a covered area).

Long answer:

The key to finding the answer is found within your own question. "Additionally, ..." implies more information came before your quoted part of the Wiki.

From that same linked wiki: "Villagers will mate depending on the number of valid doors" Make sure you have enough. You need about 3 times more doors than villagers for them to even consider breeding. This was the sole factor in breeding in previous versions. Now, it's only the first part.

Also, my intuition says the chunk that contains the new village needs to be loaded for breeding to occur. This means you need to be close to the villagers for longer periods of time.

Lastly, they need to be close to each other to breed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I added a lot of doors, and it worked :D I now have baby Priest Villager. Will they breed again, or only once?

Comment: You will find they can breed again, but you need to trade with them or give them food. It details all of this in the same wiki page you linked..

Comment: Having just set up and used 2 infinite villager breeders I suggest keeping a large wheat farm near/in the village as the number of bread (made from wheat) needed to make villagers reproduce is significantly less than other options. Additionally once you have a farmer villager, the farmer will harvest/replant the crops and make/distribute bread for you. Note that all villagers with the farmer skin (solid brown) and regardless of specific profession (fletcher, shepherd, farmer, etc) are able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have taken away 2 villagers out of their village, The rest of the village died to a raid, so now I was left with a cleric I traded, so it can get maxed out, then I took a villager, made it a farmer, traded the villager once, so now they both have been traded at least once. It was in a trapped room, only farming is ht thing to do there, no doors, no thing, but water, dirt, cobblestone, wood, and stone, and i threw a farmer half a stack of carrots, i moved further away, and the farmer started loving the other villager, and now I got a baby villager. (I don't know why I explained almost everything, ALSO DON"T FORGET THEY NEED BEDS 2 BEDS FOR 2 VILLAGERS 3RD FOR BABY. I think, bc on 1.16.5 it didn't work without beds. Also the villagers I had were from a spruce village.

Comment: But was the farmer necessary? That is the question here.